# Leer bloque de texto de un archivo

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo un problema, quiero leer todo los SELECT de un archivo. Deben estar todos separados los SELECT.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los SELECT están separados todos por un espacio.

Todos los SELECT deben ser almacenados en un **ARRAY** o en un **IEnumerable**.

Algo así quiero hacer, pero que me lea todos los SELECT:

```
public static string[] LeeArchivo()
        {
              return File.ReadAllLines(rutaArchivo)
                .TakeWhile(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
                .ToArray();
        }
```

¿Hay alguna manera de solucionarlo?

Saludos

Comment: Estan todos los selects escritos en una sola linea? y separados de las otras instrucciones por una linea ?

Comment: No están en una sola línea, sino como está en la imagen. Los demás SELECT están separadas por una única línea.

Comment: mira la segunda parte de la respuesta. es básicamente leer el archivo hasta encontrar una linea con un "Select" luego de eso en un paso interno se leerán todas las lineas hasta que se encuentre una linea en blanco y despues de eso se regresara al lector principal que seguirá buscando "select"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una manera muy simple que tienes de hacer esto es la siguiente:

```
List<string> listaSQL = new List<string>();
using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(rutaArchivo))
{
    string SQL = "";
    while (!rd.EndOfStream) //Mientras no llegue al final del documento seguimos en el bucle
    {
        string linea = rd.ReadLine(); //Leemos la linea actual
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(linea)) //Si la linea esta vacía entonces añadimos el contenido en la Lista porque ya pasa a la siguiente query
        {
            listaSQL.Add(SQL);
            SQL = "";
        }
        else //Sino seguimos construyendo la query
        {
            SQL += linea;
        }
    }
    //Al salir del bucle añadimos la ultima query
    listaSQL.Add(SQL);
}
string[] sArray = listaSQL.ToArray(); //Lo pasamos a Array
```

De esta manera vas construyendo las querys SQL linea por linea y cada vez que detecta un blanco añade la query que estabas construyendo a la lista y empieza a construir una nueva.

Comment: Me funcionó, aunque les hice unas mejoras para mi caso. Gracias. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si cada select está exactamente escrito en una línea de texto:

```
 List<string> selects = new List<string>();
 string line = "";
 new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\RutaArchivo.txt");  
 while((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)  
 {  
      if(line.StartWith("SELECT"))
      {
           selects.Add(line);
      }
 }  

 file.Close();  
 string[] array = selects.ToArray();
```

con tu codigo

```
             return File.ReadAllLines(rutaArchivo)
            .TakeWhile(s => s.StartWith("SELECT"))
            .ToArray();
```

Multi lInea

```
 List<string> selects = new List<string>();
 new System.IO.StreamReader(@"c:\RutaArchivo.txt");  
 string line = "";
 while((line = file.ReadLine()))  
 {  
      if(line.StartWith("SELECT"))
      {
           string select = "";
           while(line != "")
           {
               if(line = file.ReadLine()) 
               {
                    select +=line +"\n";

               }
           }
           selects.Add(select);
      }
 }  

 file.Close();  
 string[] array = selects.ToArray();
```

no se como hacer eso en lamda...

Comment: Que es tipo de propiedad es **line**??

Comment: ups, es un string

Comment: realizado un par de correcciones